# Compare m/d/Y format date in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to compare Current date with  $expirydate.I wrote the query as this.

```
   $expirydate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($Date . + $days . 'days'));
   $todaysdate=date('m/d/Y');    
    if(expirydate >=   $todaysdate)
   $temp[] = array('v' => (string) 'silver'); 
    else
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) 'red');
```

But it doesn't showing the right answer. it's not checking the year..Please help me..

Comment: set `date('m/d/Y', strtotime($Date . ' + ' . $days . 'days'));`

Comment: @jogesh_pi you are right !

Comment: You can drag and drop my code right in.  See my answer.

Comment: But this not comparing the year of the date

Comment: I fixed it.  Assuming $Date is a human readable date.  If not, leave off the strtotime around the $Date in my code example.

Comment: I updated my answer.  One line of code is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
$expirydate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($Date . + $days . 'days')));
   $todaysdate=strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    if(expirydate >=   $todaysdate)
   $temp[] = array('v' => (string) 'silver'); 
    else
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) 'red');
```

Comment: What is `$Date` value

Comment: I mean value echo $Date and paste that value

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this,

```
$expirydate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($Date.'+'.$days. 'days'));
```

Comment: But this not comparing the year of the date

Comment: what is the value of $Date ?

Comment: Please give sample date from your DB